# Double Pointer to Array of Integer Pointers; returning int&

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, resizable

So I made a variation of this class project. 
Class project was originally like this:

```
int* array;
array = new int[size];

// int& method
return array[index];
```

Why does this work? `array[index]` returns the value not address right? `[]` dereferences the pointer?

--- Variation --

```
int** array;
array = new int*[size];

int& RA::setget(int index)
{

    if ((index >= 0) && (index < capacity))
    {
        return **(array + index); // this part isn't working
    }
    else
        throw out_of_range("blah"); // forgot the () out_of_range(). needed to put text in the exception!!!
}
```

This doesn't work, but isn't it the same? int** array, so I do `**(array+index)`?

Comment: In C++, `operator *` of a pointer to T returns `T&`

Comment: Note that `**(array + index)` is a rather confusing way to write `*array[index]`

Answer (score 1):

The second part `**(array + index)` is not working, because you probably have not allocated memory for the second dimension.

When you do `*(array + index)`, you get a pointer to int `int*`. When you now dereference once more `**(array + index)`, you get the value, this pointer points to.

But when this pointer is not initialized, you get a segmentation fault.

To make this work, you must initialize the `int*` array

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    array[i] = new int[other_size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Olaf is correct , also to add in first part func returns int& reference to existing variable, so it correct. It would giv error if func is returnin int *, pointer/address to int